# Several problems with vb.net (made in Visual Studio 2013) and Access DB

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, insert

I'm trying to a create a windows form application in vb.net using a access database (2010) with 2 tables (as the main idea, I'm trying to create a bank creditation application). One table I use it for login, and another one to insert elements into it from a windows form.

For the login table, everything works fine, but when it comes for the second table (clients) I encounter some problems.

The table details for the clients is: ID (autonumber), first name (text), last name (text), PID (number), adress (text), city (text), marital status (text), nochildren (number), date (date/time).

I've created an insert query for the clients table that goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO `Clienti` (`nume`, `prenume`, `cnp`, `adresa`, `localitate`, `stare civila`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
```

In the Windows form I've created I have the following elements: first name (textbox), last name (textbox), PID (textbox), adress (text), city (text), marital status (text) and a button that should save those into my clients table.

The code for the save to DB button is:

```
Convert.ToInt32(cnptxt.Text)
Convert.ToInt32(numarcopiitxt.Text)

Dim cnpp As Integer
cnpp = Val(cnptxt.Text)
Dim nrcopii As Integer
nrcopii = Val(numarcopiitxt.Text)

Dim nume As String

Dim prenume As String
Dim cnp As Integer
Dim varsta As Integer
Dim adresa As String
Dim localitate As String
Dim starecivila As String
Dim numarcopii As Integer

nume = numetxt.Text
prenume = prenumetxt.Text
cnp = cnpp
varsta = varstatxt.Text
adresa = adresatxt.Text
localitate = localitatetxt.Text
starecivila = starecivilatxt.Text
numarcopii = numarcopiitxt.Text
If Me.ClientiTableAdapter.InsertQueryClienti(nume, prenume, cnp, varsta, adresa, localitate, starecivilatxt.Text) Then
    MsgBox("Client adaugat cu succes in baza de date")
Else
    MsgBox("O eroare a fost intalnita intr-unul din campurile completate. Reincercati!")
End If
```

I know it's incomplete when compared with the rows from the clients table, it's due to the problems I've encountered with the save to DB. When I run the application and I tap on the save to DB button, I receive the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "necasatorit" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

The code for InsertQueryClienti is INSERT INTO `Clienti` (`nume`, `prenume`, `cnp`, `adresa`, `localitate`, `stare civila`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and the definition for it is  Public Overloads Overridable Function InsertQueryClienti(ByVal nume As String, ByVal prenume As String, ByVal cnp As Global.System.Nullable(Of Integer), ByVal adresa As String, ByVal localitate As String, ByVal stare_civila As String, ByVal numarcopii As Global.System.Nullable(Of Integer)) As Integer

necasatorit is referring to the marital status textbox. I can't understand why it gives me that error since the textbox obviously is a string and in the table that row is set as text.

Comment: At which line does the error occur? You are trying to set a locale Integer Variable to String. It has nothing to do with your DB Definition.

Comment: The error occurs at line:   If Me.ClientiTableAdapter.InsertQueryClienti(nume, prenume, cnp, varsta, adresa, localitate, starecivilatxt.Text)

Comment: So it is not a local variable, but a paramter for InsertQueryClienti() where an Integer is excpected, but a String is given. Where does InsertQueryClienti() come from, did you write it yourself or is it auto generated somehow?

Comment: The InsertQueryClienti is created by me through the DB connection used in the application. For a better understanding how i've created it, i've used the exameple from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVkxgpeqSeY min 5:30 to 6:40.

Comment: Please add the code for InsertQueryClienti() to the question.

Comment: the code for InsertQueryClienti() is INSERT INTO `Clienti` (`nume`, `prenume`, `cnp`, `adresa`, `localitate`, `stare civila`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: Please add the full function to the question, not only the SQL Statment. You can edit your question to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry, i do not understand to what you are reffering by full function. Again, i've tried to use the same procedure that is used in the youtube link i've given you already :( Can you please be more explicit?

Comment: I can't watch youtube video at work, sorry. InsertQueryClienti() is a function/method. It has to be defined some where. What do you get, if you right click on the function name and "Goto Definition"?

Comment: Now i understand, thank you very much for your patience. The definition is  Public Overloads Overridable Function InsertQueryClienti(ByVal nume As String, ByVal prenume As String, ByVal cnp As Global.System.Nullable(Of Integer), ByVal adresa As String, ByVal localitate As String, ByVal stare_civila As String, ByVal numarcopii As Global.System.Nullable(Of Integer)) As Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of InsertQueryClienti() is as follows:

```
Public Overloads Overridable Function InsertQueryClienti(
    ByVal nume As String, 
    ByVal prenume As String, 
    ByVal cnp As Global.System.Nullable(Of Integer), 
    ByVal adresa As String, 
    ByVal localitate As String, 
    ByVal stare_civila As String, 
    ByVal numarcopii As Global.System.Nullable(Of Integer)) As Integer
```

But you are calling it this way:

```
InsertQueryClienti(nume, prenume, cnp, varsta, adresa, localitate, starecivilatxt.Text)
```

The first three parameter `nume`, `prenume`, `cnp` are identical, but after that you use `varsta`.
This shifts everything to the right. `starecivilatxt.Text` is passed as the last parameter which is
of type Integer.

This way the parameter are in the same order in the definition and the call.

```
InsertQueryClienti(nume, prenume, cnp, adresa, localitate, starecivilatxt.Text, ???)
```

I don't know what the last parameter should be. Maybe `varsta`?

Comment: Indeed, the varsta parameter is missing, i will try to add it now ( don't know how, but i will try ) and i will come back with an answer as soon as possible. Thank you very much

Comment: yeah, well i tried to make the program work as intended but i failed. Do you think that you can help me remake the design of the windows form from which i should insert the data in the DB? Maybe we could switch on FB or mail? Please, i'm desperate to make it work :(

Comment: Sorry can't do that. But your approach seems mostly fine. If you have another question, post it here on SO (as a new question) and I'm sure, somebody will help you.